# Question about probabilities of independent events?

Tags: probability

Consider a fair coin toss. Let $H$ be the event that a heads was thrown. Let $T$ be the event a tail was thrown. Given $H$ and $T$ are disjoint are then independent?

I don't really know how to do this. My initial though was yes but then I though for independent events $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ but $A\cap B$ can't really happen since there is only one toss. So I'm unsure?

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what you have said in your second paragraph is correct: $P(H\cap T)=0$, and $P(H)P(T)=\frac14$, these are not equal so the events are not independent.

A useful informal way to think about this: two events are independent when the occurrence or non-occurrence of either does not affect the probability of the other happening.  In this case, the events are certainly not independent since a head occurring makes the probability of tails zero.

Comment: Great that makes sense thanks!

Comment: @NathanK When events are mutually exclusive; they **cannot** be independent. If David's answer is the best one provided and it helped you, you should accept it.